# How to get API error message from using Laravel and Guzzle

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using guzzle and laravel to call an API however when I get an error from the API, I can't view the error message sent back from the API. Laravel / Guzzle gives a default error Client error: 400.

How do I view the error message sent back?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the request which solved my issue.

```
'http_errors' => false
```